# Regexp not working

Tags: latex, auctex, text-editing, replace, regular-expressions

I messed up my latex code; I need to replace `\cite[42]{source}.` with `.\cite[42]{source}` and `\cite{source}.` with `.\cite{source}`. I tried `\\cite\(.*\)\}\. -> .\\cite\1\}` but I got an error: `Invalid use of '\' in replacement text`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't backslash the curly brace `}` in the replacement text.  This works, when entered at the `query-replace-regexp` prompt:

FROM: `\\cite\(.+\)}\.`

TO: `.\\cite\1}`

Comment: Why did you use + instead of *?

Comment: `+` says "one or more characters after `\cite` and before the closing brace" which means that `\cite}` will not be matched.  It's not a big deal, but I thought it was cleaner.